# select average of top 3 for each specific sql job

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```html
SELECT  jobs.Job_ID AS JobID ,
                    jobs.NAME AS JobName ,
                    act.start_execution_date AS StartExecutionDate ,
                    AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) AS AvgDurationMin ,
                    CASE 
  --If job average less than 5 minutes then limit is avg+10 minutes
                         WHEN AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) <= 5
                         THEN ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) ) + 2
  --If job average greater than 5 minutes then limit is avg*limit percentage
                         ELSE ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100))
                                )
                    END AS DurationLimit ,
                    DATEDIFF(MI, act.start_execution_date, GETDATE()) AS [CurrentDuration]
            FROM    @currently_running_jobs crj
                    INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobs AS jobs ON crj.job_id = jobs.job_id
                    INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobactivity AS act ON act.job_id = crj.job_id
                                                              AND act.stop_execution_date IS NULL
                                                              AND act.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
                    INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobhistory AS hist ON hist.job_id = crj.job_id
                                                              AND hist.step_id = 0
            WHERE   crj.job_state = 1 --and jobs.NAME = 'long_running_testing'
            GROUP BY jobs.job_ID ,
                    jobs.NAME ,
                    act.start_execution_date ,
                    DATEDIFF(MI, act.start_execution_date, GETDATE())
     HAVING  CASE WHEN AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) <= 5
         THEN (AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100))) + 2
                            --THEN ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) ) + 1  
                         ELSE ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100))
                                )
                    END < DATEDIFF(MI, act.start_execution_date, GETDATE())
```

Can someone please help me to extract the average    run_duration of   recent three entries of job's partitioned by job_name?

Please find      the below script which I used to extract information
   of    recent       three run_duration partitioned by job_name, but it
   calculates the average of all run_duration .

Here I need only the recent three run_duration average count.

[image: a boring table with guids and datetimes and sooper seecrit JobNames, carefully redacted]

```
SELECT top 1 with  ties  jobs.Job_ID AS JobID , AVG(FLOOR(run_duration/100%100 )),
                    jobs.NAME AS JobName ,
                    act.start_execution_date AS StartExecutionDate 
 from msdb..sysjobs AS jobs
inner join msdb..sysjobactivity AS act ON act.job_id = jobs.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobhistory AS hist ON hist.job_id = jobs.job_id AND hist.step_id = 0

 GROUP BY jobs.job_ID ,
                    jobs.NAME 
            ,      act.start_execution_date ,hist.run_duration,
                   DATEDIFF(MI, act.start_execution_date, GETDATE())
order by  case when row_number() over (partition by jobs.NAME order by hist.run_duration desc) <= 3 then 0 else 1 end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a CTE would simplify it.

```
with SeqByJob_cte as (  SELECT  jobs.NAME AS JobName
                            ,hist.run_duration
                            ,row_number() over(partition by jobs.NAME order by act.start_execution_date desc) as seq 
                    from    msdb..sysjobs AS jobs
                            inner join msdb..sysjobactivity AS act ON act.job_id = jobs.job_id
                            INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobhistory AS hist ON hist.job_id = jobs.job_id AND hist.step_id = 0)
select  avg(run_duration) as AvgOf3MostRecentRuns
        ,CASE 
    --If job average less than 5 minutes then limit is avg+10 minutes
                     WHEN AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) <= 5
                     THEN ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) ) + 2
    --If job average greater than 5 minutes then limit is avg*limit percentage
                     ELSE ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100))
                            )
                END AS DurationLimit
        ,JobName
from    SeqByJob_cte
where   seq <= 3
group by JobName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot cyndi..and can you please guide me where i can use case statement here..The scenorio is i want to use case like case (1) --If job average less than 5 minutes then limit is avg+10 minutes case (2) --If job average greater than 5 minutes then limit is avg*limit percentage.. And please find the t-sql in the comment which have created to calculate avgerage,duration_limit and current_run_time. Can you please help me in this..

Comment: i have added the script above in the snippet(new one)..can u please have a look on it..it is like  below,posted full query in the above snippet..  CASE 
  --If job average less than 5 minutes then limit is avg+10 minutes
                         WHEN AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) <= 5
                         THEN ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100)) ) + 2
  --If job average greater than 5 minutes then limit is avg*limit percentage
                         ELSE ( AVG(FLOOR(run_duration / 100))
                                )
                    END AS DurationLimit ,

Comment: I added the duration limit to the final select statement in the answer.  Does this help?